# how to run Specflow AfterStep Hooks for Particular Scenario only

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, specrun

I have my Weba utomation framework and i'm adding few of the scenarios for API level testing. In my Hooks "After step" i want to make it work for API level testing diffeently . like dont go to default "After step". How can i do that ?

I've added the tag to feature level and tried to use that tag  but it is still going to old Afterstep.

```
[AfterStep("@API1")]
    public static void AfterSteps()

    {

    }
```

original Afterstep

```
[AfterStep]
    public static void AfterStep()
    {
    }
```

ofcourse i need to change the method name to "Aftersteps" for my new Afterstep hooks.

Please help me what is wrong here ?

Comment: Can you explain more what the "AfterStep" hook is doing? You might be better off with a `Given` at the beginning of your Scenario, or adding some steps to a `Background` instead.

Comment: @GregBurghardt :- My after step is just logging out the browser and clearing the cookies and cache . However with API tests we dont want to Open the browser. in my Aftestep we have a Pagemanager class which will invoke the Browser. so basically with the API tag i just to avoid my tests to go to default Afterstep.  Let me know if you need more explanation ?

 Also i'm 100 % confident i don't want Given or Background .

Answer (score 1):

At the attribute you do not need the @.
So will do it:

```
[AfterStep("API1")]
```

Comment: :-  yeah i figured it out that one we dont need @ and i removed it . However my tests are still going through both the AftesStep hooks . the one with API tag and the one without it . So just wondering how can we solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have your orignal AfterStep to run when the category API1 is set, use the following code:

```
        if(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("API1"))
        {
            return;
        }
```